# How to remove the first two characters of a QString

Tags: c++, qt, replace, qstring

How would I remove the the first two characters of a QString or if I have to put it a StackOverflows layman's terms:

```
QString str = "##Name" //output: ##Name
```

to

```
output: Name
```

So far I have used this small piece of code:

```
if(str.contains("##"))
{
    str.replace("##","");
}
```

..but it doesn't work as I would need to have **"##"** in some other strings, but not at the beginning.

The first two characters may occur to be **"%$"** and **"#@"** as well and that mostly the reason why I need to delete the first two characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: str = str.right(str.size()-2) ?

Comment: str.remove(0,2) ? I never used Qt, but the documentation on QString looks like... very complete.

Comment: Timbo got it right!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This the syntax to remove the two first characters.

```
str.remove(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`QString::mid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#mid) function for this:

```
QString trimmed = str.mid(2);
```

But if you wish to modify the string in place, you would be better off using [`QString::remove`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#remove) as others have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [remove(const QRegExp &rx)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#remove-4)

Removes every occurrence of the regular expression rx in the string, and returns a reference to the string. For example:

```
QString str = "##Name" //output: ##Name
    str.remove(QRegExp("[#]."));
    //strr == "Name"
```

Comment: This is not the best answer for the question but it solved my problem: I wanted to remove all occurence of a given character.